# Selenium Chromedriver not going to url on launch

Tags: c#, selenium

just started trying out `Selenium` and am having trouble getting a script to run with `ChromeDriver`.
All I'm trying to get it to do is open the browser and go the url in the script.

Problem is, the browser opens, but then nothing happens, the browser just sits there doing nothing.

Initially I just had the following line, but `ChromeDriver` kept crashing, I added the lines you see in the main script and the crashing has stopped but it still does not work.

First script:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

    namespace WebDriverDemo
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Libraries\");
                driver.Url = "https://www.google.com";
            }
        }
    }
```

Tried this in the end with no crash but no result either.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace WebDriverDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArguments("test-type");
            options.ToCapabilities();
            ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\Libraries\");
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
            // Tried both of the below
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
            driver.Url = "https://www.google.com";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That generally means that the driver version doesn't match the browser version.

Answer (score 0):

Please download the latest chrome drive.Replace the old driver. Try to run the same program again and observe. If we update our browser check the drive for that.

Answer (score 0):

I was using chromedriver and recently I started facing similar issue.I moved to IE driver .Either download latest version of chromedriver or try using IE driver, if the purpose could be met.

Regards,
Anuradha

Answer (score 0):

Please try using latest chrome driver. You can download it from [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.30/)